# Generating URL through routing, using ID from a form field (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, forms

Say I want to display user details like so:
http://www.mysite.com/user/1

I set a route up like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("UserDetails", "user/"{id}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "Details" });
```

Then my controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    User currentUser = _userRepository.GetUser(id);
    if (currentUser == null) return View("NotFound");
    return View(currentUser);
}
```

So far so good. Everything works like I expect. Now I also want a form where one can enter the ID to look up then click Submit to get the same result. eg:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("Details","User",FormMethod.Post); %>
<input type="text" value="" name="id" id="userid" />
<%= Html.Button("Search For User","submit","searchforuser"; %>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

This is where I'm currently lost. I don't want to just have [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] and use a RedirectToAction if possible. I just want to take whatever number they input - say 38 - and go to www.mysite.com/user/38

Is this even possible with straight MVC? I'm sure there are jQuery-related ways but so far have had no luck getting anything beyond a basic jQuery alert working so don't really want to waste any more time on it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC will automatically match by name query parameters (for `GET`) or form input files (for `POST`) to the action parameters by name. Unfortunately, your  id does not match the action parameter name, so MVC can't match them. To fix this, you can:

- change the id on the `<input type="text" value="" name="id" id="userid" />` from `userid` to `id`
- change the parameter name of the Details action from `id` to `userid` (and don't forget to update your route as well)

I just confirmed that at least the first one fixes the issue on MVC2 RC. I don't have MVC1, so I can't check if it works there as well, but as far as I know there are no major differences in how MVC1 and MVC2 match parameters.

Comment: Since you're the only one who bothered replying, I see no choice other than to accept your answer :)